# Items with many columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable

I have a database table `Products`, and a product can have hundreds of features and properties (Flexible number of unique properties). Each property may be used by users to filter products. How can I store all these details in the database?

Currently, I am storing each property in a different row for a product in the `ProductProperties` table. This makes my database huge. For 1000 products with 200 properties, this results in 200,000 rows in the `ProductProperty` table.

Another solution I am planning is to save `ProductProperty` as JSON in a `varchar` column, but this lacks flexibility and I cannot filter rows using a T-SQL query.

Any better approach for this scenario?

Comment: It would probably be best to break your product table down in to multiple tables like having a ProductType table for example. Then have different 'Properties saved in different tables'. Now when a user is searching for data they can just join the tables in the query and filter down that way without having on massive table.  will also mean you can be more flexible.

Comment: Each products has flexible unique columns, Some products has 100 features, some will have 300+.

Comment: Yes, I think someone as already posted this as an answer but you would split this data into a Features tables so again it is not all held in one table but managed across multiple tables. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to search the features.

The traditional method would be to have a `ProductFeatures` tables.  This would have one column per product and per feature:

```
create table ProductFeatures (
    ProductFeatureId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    ProductId int not null references Products(ProductId),
    FeatureId int not null references Features(FeaturId)
);
```

You can then use this table for filtering features individually.

This is particularly handy if the number of features is flexible.

Under some circumstances, you might want to store the features as a text column, building a full text index on them.  JSON is another possibility.  However, the junction table is the first approach that I would consider.

Comment: Will it make the select query slow  searching for a property in large number of rows ??? How about the number, date columns ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, with more detail about what "features" mean.

Answer (score -1):

Do u have your Properties Information in a text file ? If yes, then you have two possibilities:
1- Is to structure your text to be distingushed and filled in your database automatically through a code (i.e Java code ), and you can find a lot of theses codes on the internet!
2- is to do that manulaay , which is the more difficult option.
Both options need manual stuff to do unfortunately but i find it easier to build up an algorithm which fits with my Text structure !